# pyspark: split a single RDD to multiple RDD by value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I cannot find answer.
If I have RDD

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('a', [1,2,3]), ('b',[4,5,6])])
```

where each value is a list.
Are there ways to split the RDD, such that it becomes

```
sc.parallelize([('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('b',4),('b',5),('b'6)])
```

where now each value is one of element of the lists, and match the key.
I roughly know the solution. We can first `collect()`

```
a = rdd.collect()
```

and then reassign a RDD as

```
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([x for x in a])
```

But if RDD is huge, the `collect()` will be very time consuming. We have to think about it by scale. Are there any distributed ways to do it? (like using `lambda function` .. etc) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a task for `flatMap`:

```py
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(x[0], v) for v in x[1]]).collect()
# [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 4), ('b', 5), ('b', 6)]
```

---

Here the lambda function takes one key value pair from the original rdd and map the key to each individual value:

```py
lamb = lambda x: [(x[0], v) for v in x[1]]

lamb(('a', [1,2,3]))
# [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)]
```

`flatMap` will map this operation to each key value pair and flatten the result.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I need!